# How to display images retrieved from JSON url?

Tags: c#, json, url, windows-phone-7, visual-c#-express-2010

I am clueless on how to proceed. How do I display the images from a url containing JSON in C#? Please provide a code sample, if possible.

Comment: What do you mean by JSON url? Do you have an example? If you have an URL you can just set Image.Source = new BitmapImage(url);

Comment: URL containing JSON, i mean :) I need to specifically grab a particular user's image, for example, how do I achieve that?

Comment: I still don't understant what you mean with `URL containing JSON`?. Some samples?

Comment: @mojojo: Its common that some developers use the term "URL" inappropriately to mean the resource addressed by the URL.  A URL is actually simply a string that addresses a specific __resource__ found on the web.   I suspect what you mean is that the JSON retrieved the url contains references to images.

Comment: @anthonyWjones wouldn't that be URI? Sorry - I am a beginner, so learning as I proceed.

Comment: @mojojo: No URIs are a superset of URLs (i.e., all URLs are also URIs)  A URI though is merely an __Identifier__ and is designed to be __Universally__ unique but is not necessarily a reference to resource that can be downloaded (hence the __R__ in the acronym is a bit misleading).  A URL is a URI that specifies the __Location__ of a __Resource__ that _can_ be downloaded (or indeed written to).

Comment: @mojojo:  Include in your question a sample of the JSON from which you would like to retrieve images.

Answer (score 0):

If what you have is a URL and this URL points at a JSON resource and that resource contains some image URLs, then you would use the following calls:

1. WebClient.DownloadStringAsync() - to download the JSON resource as string
2. DataContractJsonSerializer.Deserialize() - to deserialize JSON into an object graph (you need to define classes annotated with DataContract and DataMember attributes corresponding to the JSON structure.
3. Get the image URL from the deserialized objects and use it to set the image source like this: Image.Source = new BitmapImage(url);

This should get you on the right track in your searches. Otherwise the question is too broad.